# Find next file (but not FindNextFile)

Tags: windows, winapi

If a user opens a file in a program (for example using `GetOpenFileNameW`, `DragQueryFileW`, command line argument, or whatever else to get the path, and a subsequent `CreateFileW` call), is there a way to find the next file in the parent directory of the opened file?

The obvious solution is to cycle through the results from `FindNextFileW` or `NtQueryDirectoryFileEx` until the opened file is encountered, and just open the next file.

However, this seems undesireable.

First, because these functions use paths (instead of for example a handle), the original file is decoupled from the search algorithm, so the original file might not even get encountered in that search. This is not much of an issue (as failing in this case is the expected outcome), and it probably could be resolved with (temporarly) changing the sharing mode, using `LockFile` or similar (though I would like to avoid that).

Second, this cycling search would have to be done every time, because the contents of the directory might have changed (retaining `hFindFile` does not work, because only `FindFirstFileW` calls `NtQueryDirectoryFileEx` and enumerates the contents of the directory). Which seems like unnecessary work and might even affect performance (for example if the directory contains a lot of files).

In theory any file system has some way of enumerating the files in a directory. Meaning there is some ordered data structure of the files' metadata. And getting the next file should only involve going back from the existing file handle to that file's entry, and then getting the next entry from that data structure. So there does not seem to be a fundamental reason why this cannot be done more sanely.

I thought maybe there exist a better way to do this somewhere in WinAPI...

Same question for finding the previous file.

Comment: The enumeration handle is not the file handle. Getting the "next file" involves going back to the enumeration handle and asking for the next file entry. But the enumeration handle doesn't exist. You have to make one. (Also, it's not clear what the "next" file is, since the order of enumeration is unspecified. It may not match the order shown to the user in a file listing.)

Comment: But there does exist some native enumeration, right? So there should be some simple way to get from a file handle to its position in that enumeration (without the need to explicitly recreate the enumeration and search for the required file), and then increment that position. It does not really matter what the order is, just that all files will be enumerated.

Comment: The native enumeration is "Open a handle to the directory, read the file names from it." But when you are given a path on the command line, the enumeration handle has probably been closed a long time ago. There is no "seek to a point in an enumeration that matches a given file name" API. In FAT, for example, a directory is a linked list of file names. There is no random access to a linked list.

Comment: Of course, given some random path, explicit enumeration is inevitable. But given a handle to an open file, as long as the file keeps track of its link, resuming the enumeration should be trivial (the access is not truly random).

Comment: Even if it is as trivial as you say, there is no API for it. (For one thing, if the handle is to a hard link, which directory should it enumerate from? Also, whose permission do you use for the security check. The caller, or the opener?)

Comment: I suppose an arbitrary decision would be made concerning the issues you outlined. Probably mimicking as closely as possible the behaviour that an implementation that uses `FindNextFileW` would exert... Anyway, thanks for answering!

Comment: @RaymondChen Except that the Windows photo viewer (XP...8) does this. After double-clicking a file in Explorer, Photo viewer/"preview" knows the Explorer sort order of the folder and will correctly go to the next file.

Comment: That's because it is given the [list of neighboring items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.fileactivatedeventargs.neighboringfilesquery?view=winrt-22000) as part of launch.

Comment: Older apps can register a command in the form of a DropTarget, and then query the site for SID_FolderView and extract the view items that way.